# How to Reorder Sliver's Z-Order in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I control sliver's z-order? Here is CustomScrollView with one header sliver (transparent gray, pinned to the top) and SliverList with orange and green containers. I want the header to be below the SliverList.

At the same time header can contain some button which should be available to tap when visible. So, Stack won't work here since it scroll view above will block all interaction.

[image: screenshot]